# Calcular el porcentaje de una columna que no pertenece a una tabla en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas

tengo un problema, estoy tratando de realizar una consulta en el cual necesito saber el importe de ventas de cada producto y que porcentaje representa en total.

este es el código que he usado (da error)

```
SELECT P.ProductName as 'Nombre del Producto',
SUM(P.UnitPrice * P.UnitsOnOrder) as 'Importe de Ventas'
SUM(('Importe de Ventas') / 100) as 'Porcentaje del total'
FROM Northwind..Products as P
GROUP BY P.ProductName;
go
```

El problema está en que necesito saber la suma total del importe de ventas para luego calcular el porcentaje que le corresponde a cada uno pero no encuentro la manera lograr eso.

Si ejecuto el código sin la tercera línea me arroja este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el modelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Christian, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
 T.Producto as 'Nombre del Producto', 
 T.ImporteVentas as 'Importe de Ventas', 
 (T.ImporteVentas/sum(T.ImporteVentas)) * 100 as 'Porcentaje del total'
from
(
 select P.ProductName as Producto,
 sum(P.UnitPrice * P.UnitsOnOrder) as ImporteVentas,
 from Northwind..Products as P
 group by P.ProductName
)T
```

Lo primero que haces es una **subconsulta**, donde vas a obtener el **nombre del producto** y su **importe de ventas total** (por cada producto). Posteriormente haces una **consulta general** sobre esta **subconsulta**, y es aquí donde obtendrías el porcentaje por cada producto utilizando esta expresión:

```
(T.ImporteVentas/sum(T.ImporteVentas)) * 100
```